# Name or Adjective for Ellipse with very different (or very similar) scales

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, ellipsoids

I am looking for an adjective or word to describe an ellipse (or ellipsoid, in more dims) where the length of the principal axes are of roughly the same order of magnitude $\mathcal{O}(a) = \mathcal{O}(b)$ (including equal, i.e. a circle).

For instance:

- $a=2$, $b=5$ would be something like an "isometric" ellipse (or ellipsoid)
- $a=2$, $b=50$ would be something like an "asometric" ellipse (or ellipsoid) since they are of different orders of magnitude

Comment: Low/high eccentricity respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am aware of no special name. But is a name was to be given, I would say very plainly "with high or low" **eccentricity**  due to formula

$$e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}} \ \ \text{on a scale} \ \ 0 \le e < 1$$

(the minimum $0$ for a circle, $1$ cannot be attained because we would have then a parabola).

Besides, for the 3D case of an ellipsoid with semiaxes

$$a \ge b \ge c,$$

I would like to attract your attention on two specific names for the case of equality:

- if $a = b > c$: "**Prolate** spheroid" (in fact ellipsoid) (rugby ball),
- if $a > b = c$: "**Oblate** spheroid" (ideal Cinderella's pumpkin...).

The prolate spheroidals, in particular, are connected with various applications:

- a 3D [coordinates' system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolate_spheroidal_coordinates)
- orthogonal functions. See for example this [article](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-07/S0002-9939-07-08739-4/S0002-9939-07-08739-4.pdf) explaining how that these functions are at the same time orthogonal in $L^2(-1,1)$ and in $L^2(-\infty,+\infty)$...